# How to get base_url() in a Joomla 2.5 article page?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I want to link a pdf file in a Joomla(2.5) article page.
This pdf file resides in

**PROJECT_NAME/pdf/filename** directory.

Is there any solution by using which I don't need to write the whole path statically or I can say if there is any way to get base_url in article?

Same way I also need to link some menu items in article text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to add just Link to PDF then no need to add full path

it will work just normal image or normal page link

just try to check with  remove `/` before your `href` link and let me know wether it is working or not

In my project it is working just having

```
href="dir1/dir2/dir3/file.pdf"
```

if you try this

```
href="/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.pdf"
```

then you will have different address in both case

in my case `href="dir1/dir2/dir3/file.pdf"` it is working

Comment: Ohh! God...Was it the only mistake????
It worked by removing that extra "/" in the editor href link.
And due to this got another solution to have PHP code in Joomla Article Content.

Thank you Chintan Gor & @Rémi Delhaye.

Answer (score 2):

`JURI::base()` looks like the command you looks for.

[Documentation here](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/base)

*Note:*

> In a template you can use the shortcut `$this->baseurl` instead of `JURI::base( true )`.

Comment: I have a "click here to see pdf" in my article.
How to link it to the pdf file i mentioned in the question?

JURI::base() is okay but I want to have it in editor at article adding.

Comment: I think you can concatenate your `JURI::base()` with the path of the PDF, and add it to the `href=""` of your `click here to see pdf` link with code.

Comment: I got "DirectPHP-plugin" plugin, which allowed me to write php code between <?php ... ?> and it is working.
Other than that I don't think there is any solution.
JURI::base() works there...:)

Comment: I think it is the only working solution for your problem, glad to hear that it works for you :)